# Media query to differentiate desktop from iPad in landscape mode

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm building a website with responsive design. I need to differentiate layout between tablet in landscape mode and desktop with media queries. These are the media queries right now:

```
<link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="desktop.css" 
media="only screen and (min-width: 801px)" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="tablet.css" 
media="only screen and (min-width: 629px) and (max-width: 800px) and 
(orientation:portrait), 
only screen and (min-height:629px) and (max-height:800px) and 
(orientation:landscape)" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Problem is that `desktop.css` is included for tablets in landscape mode. iPad in landscape is `1024px` wide, this is a resolution common for PCs. How with media queries can I differentiate `1000px` wide dekstop from a tablet in landscape mode?

P.S. I have to use media queries becasue the website will be cached/CDNed and so on. Any server side detection won't work.

P.S.2.

```
<link href="desktop.css" 
media="only screen and (min-width: 801px), 
not only screen and (min-height:629px) and (max-height:800px) and 
(orientation:landscape)" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I have found 'device-aspect-ratio' feature. It should be higher than 1 for desktop, and smaller than 1 of tablets. I will test it now.

Comment: Not tested on different browsers yet, but I have fixed the issue with:

<link href="desktop.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 801px) and 
(min-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1)" rel="stylesheet"/>
Now desktop.css in not included on landscape iPad.

Comment: This is cool.  Are you detecting if it's a mobile device by the `min-device-aspect-ratio`?  Is this so you can style separately for devices and desktop?  The question would have more motivation to answer if we knew _why_ you wanted to differentiate.  For example, "I want to know when I have a viewport of `1000px` on tablet and desktop so I can make the layout of the buttons bigger on tablet"  Have you looked at [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)?  Always have lots of useful stuff on there.

Comment: I'm not detecting mobile devices with min-device-aspect-ratio. Detecting desktop is enough for me.
And yes, I got different design for tablets and for desktop. Different design, and different way of scrolling. Big buttons for mouse, and no buttons, just finger touch scrolling, for tablets.

Comment: It would be better to adjust for touch-capable devices by testing for that feature instead of testing for screen size/aspect ratio and assuming touch. See [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for information on doing that.

Comment: @Brent: Undoable. I want to serve right layout before JS is executed.

Answer (score 4):

I plan to use Detectizr, a plugin for Modernizr

https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr

E.g.

```
// adds html class: 'desktop', 'tablet' or 'mobile' to aid styling
Modernizr.Detectizr.detect({ detectDeviceModel: false, detectScreen: false, detectOS: false, detectBrowser: false, detectPlugins: false });

// hack: for some reason, modernizr is chopping off the 'mobile' part off the 'ui-mobile' class needed by jquery mobile
$("html").removeClass("ui-");
$("html").addClass("ui-mobile");
```

Ending up with a html tag looking something like this:

```
<html lang="en" class="js tablet ui-mobile    landscape">
```

And the use the classes 'desktop' and 'tablet' to aid styling